# Update DynamoDB Entries at Specific Times

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table where each entry has a time and a status. I would like to have DynamoDB update the status at the entry's specified time. What is the recommended way to do this without running a server? Basically I want to have TTL trigger a custom lambda instead of delete my entry, but I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions for this.

- Using Lambda Scheduled Events (Create a Lambda function with a scheduled frequency to run and update the status if it matches the TTL).
- Using CloudWatch Events to Trigger a Lambda function which does the status update.

For the above two approaches, the time of update depends on the frequency the Lambda function executes.

- Use [DynamoDB TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html) to trigger a Lambda function once the specified TTL is reached. At this time you can change the status and create a new item. (The limitation of this approach is that DynamoDB can take up to 48 hours to delete an expired item, which can also delay the status change time up to 48 hours from specified)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to setup an AWS cloudwatch event that calls a lambda function on a schedule you decide.

The Lambda function can then update the DynamoDB data for you.

This will work as long as you are OK with scheduling things to happen at minute, or slower, intervals - i.e. you can't get things updated every second.